# Set up sharing sets

Tags: community, lightning-community, partner-communities, sharing-sets

The idea is that a community user will create an Opportunity. The opportunity will then be re-assigned to another community user for processing (this user does not belong to the previous account).

I have tried to define a sharing set so that the community users that created the record will still be able to view while they are being worked. The problem is that the only field that is not available to choose is CreatedBy

Comment: Where are you not able to choose created by field?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing sets are only for sharing records among community users of the same account.  The object records have to be linked to the account of the community users.

If you are using Customer Community Plus or Partner Community licenses, then you can use [manual sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=granting_access_to_records.htm&type=5) to share records across  different accounts.

If you are using Customer Community license only, then you can't share data across accounts unless you set the object default to Public, but that means all community users can see all those records.

Comment: Thank you for your answer David, I will try with manual sharing :)